# Could not launch managed proxy executable

Tags: 14.04, proxy, tor

I have problem with tor and obfsproxy for using bridges on ubuntu 14.04. Tor could not start obfsproxy and always return permission denied.

```
grep -v "^#" /etc/tor/torrc | sed '/^$/d'

UseBridges 1
Bridge obfs2 192.36.27.216:55313 fccb4bf2a7b89b070902bdd05923c255fb4b0bdb 
ClientTransportPlugin obfs2,obfs3 exec /usr/bin/obfsproxy --managed
```

---

```
tail -f /var/log/tor/log

Aug 01 13:06:30.000 [notice] Tor 0.2.4.23 (git-05b81fcd2a655c5a) opening new log file.
Aug 01 13:06:30.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Aug 01 13:06:30.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Aug 01 13:06:30.000 [warn] OpenSSL version from headers does not match the version we're running with. If you get weird crashes, that might be why. (Compiled with 1000105f:     OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013; running with 1000106f: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014).
Aug 01 13:06:33.000 [warn] Could not launch managed proxy executable at '/usr/bin/obfsproxy' ('Permission denied').
Aug 01 13:06:34.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server.
Aug 01 13:06:34.000 [warn] We were supposed to connect to bridge '192.36.27.216:55313' using pluggable transport 'obfs2', but we can't find a pluggable transport proxy supporting 'obfs2'. This can happen if you haven't provided a ClientTransportPlugin line, or if your pluggable transport proxy stopped running.
```

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Follow my question here: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/obfsproxy-problem-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 8):

**Premise**
How to configure Tor and Obfsproxy:
- https://www.torproject.org/projects/obfsproxy-debian-instructions

According with this bug report:
https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/6996
 ... the obfsproxy permission error is triggered by the tor init script ( at least on debian/ubuntu ) because of tor apparmor wrong script (`/etc/apparmor.d/system_tor`)

so basically approuch is to stop the service and launch tor directly so a simple and straight:

```
sudo service tor stop && tor
```

this should work ( don't use `sudo` to launch tor or you will get a different error :(

**Better solution**
is to fix the apparmor tor profile so that the tor service start correctly

1. edit this file `/etc/apparmor.d/system_tor`
2. add this line `/usr/bin/obfsproxy  Ux,`
3. restart apparmor service (`sudo service apparmor restart` )

So the profile should look something like this:

```
# vim:syntax=apparmor
#include <tunables/global>

profile system_tor {
  #include <abstractions/tor>

  owner /var/lib/tor/** rwk,
  owner /var/log/tor/* w,

  /usr/bin/obfsproxy  Ux,  ## this is the FIX

  /{,var/}run/tor/control w,
  /{,var/}run/tor/tor.pid w,
  /{,var/}run/tor/control.authcookie w,
  /{,var/}run/tor/control.authcookie.tmp rw,

  # Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
  #include <local/system_tor>
}
```

Comment: As you said, it's a bug. I had to disable default init script to prevent conflict and I'm using simple script in '/etc/init' folder atm to run tor automaticely.

Comment: In later versions of Ubuntu, this needs another line in `/etc/apparmor.d/system_tor` or else it won't be able to stop the `obfsproxy` process when the `tor` service is stopped: `signal (send) set=("term") peer="unconfined",`

See https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13716

Answer (score 1):

I modified **apparmor** profile **/etc/apparmor.d/system_tor**, just added three lines in it:

```
/usr/bin/obfsproxy PUx,
profile /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.obfsproxy {
}
```

Whole file sample:

```
# vim:syntax=apparmor
#include <tunables/global>

profile system_tor flags=(attach_disconnected) {
  #include <abstractions/tor>

  /usr/bin/obfsproxy PUx,

  profile /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.obfsproxy {
  }

  owner /var/lib/tor/** rwk,
  owner /var/lib/tor/ r,
  owner /var/log/tor/* w,

  # During startup, tor (as root) tries to open various things such as
  # directories via check_private_dir().  Let it.
  /var/lib/tor/** r,

  /{,var/}run/tor/ r,
  /{,var/}run/tor/control w,
  /{,var/}run/tor/socks w,
  /{,var/}run/tor/tor.pid w,
  /{,var/}run/tor/control.authcookie w,
  /{,var/}run/tor/control.authcookie.tmp rw,
  /{,var/}run/systemd/notify w,

  # Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
  #include <local/system_tor>
}
```

line

```
/usr/bin/obfsproxy  PUx,
```

I took from the post above

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Ubuntu require `/etc/apparmor/system_tor` to be like this:

```
# vim:syntax=apparmor
#include <tunables/global>

profile system_tor {
  #include <abstractions/tor>

  owner /var/lib/tor/** rwk,
  owner /var/log/tor/* w,

  /usr/bin/obfsproxy  PUx,  ## this is the FIX

  /{,var/}run/tor/control w,
  /{,var/}run/tor/tor.pid w,
  /{,var/}run/tor/control.authcookie w,
  /{,var/}run/tor/control.authcookie.tmp rw,

  # Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
  #include <local/system_tor>
}
```

Make note of the `PUx` instead of the `Ux` as would be used in earlier versions of Ubuntu.